# C++ if-else statement inside cout

Tags: c++, if-statement, ternary-operator, cout, ostream

I want to do something like this:

```
ostream& table(ostream& os, myClass& obj, bool foo1, bool foo2) {
    os << (foo1 ? obj.getFoo1() : "") << (foo2 ? obj.getFoo2() : "");
    return os;
}
```

Now my main problem is, that i don't need an `else` statement. Even if I can't use the ternary operator without an `else`, I need to send space like `" "`. I would really like to use `" "` but my `obj.getFoo` does not return any string value (it returns an integer). And for integers there is no 'space'.

Is there any way to get an `if-else` statement inside `cout` (obviously without the `else`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it if you use [`to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string):

```
ostream& table(ostream& os, myClass& obj, bool foo1, bool foo2) {
  os << (foo1 ? std::to_string(obj.getFoo1()) : "") 
     << (foo2 ? std::to_string(obj.getFoo2()) : "");

  return os;
}
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b4b0d2e40867bb5e)

Answer (score 1):

I personally would simply do:

```
ostream& table(ostream& os, myClass& obj, bool foo1, bool foo2) {
   if (foo1)
      os << obj.getFoo1();
   if (foo2)
      os << obj.getFoo2(); 
  return os;
}
```

The code generated will be nearly identical anyway, and will avoid the printing of an empty string, which will need some code.

The ternary operator is great for when you have a really long set of arguments to a function and only want to vary a little bit:

```
func(arg1, arg2, arg3, (flag)?arg4a:arg4b, arg5, arg6, arg7);
```

[E.g. printf statement]

But for the case of a stream output, it serves really no useful purpose, since the code for:

```
 a << b << c;
```

is the the same as:

```
 a << b; a << c;
```

[well, as near as, anyway]

Comment: I will have 49 different foo's. That´s why i am looking for a short way.

Comment: Then I suspect you are doing something a little bit wrong (or VERY wrong). But the short version is to add another function: `print_if_true(ostream& os, bool cond, Type thing) { if (cond) os << thing; }  }` and then call `print_if_true(os, foo1, obj.getFoo1());` etc. If `obj.getFoo1()` is returning differnet types, you may need to make it a templated function.

Answer (score 0):

Use `foo1 ? std::to_string(obj.getFoo1()) : std::string(" ")`.